# Generalization of homotopy groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, spheres

Studying homotopy groups, I faced the definition of pointed homotopy, denoting the homotopy groups as $[\mathbb{S}^n, X]^0$.

In order to define a well-defined structure of group, we can think to $\mathbb{S}^n$ as $I^n/\partial I^n$ and $[\mathbb{S}^n, X]^0 = [(I^n,\partial I^n)(X,x_0)]$ maps of pair.

Explicit homotopies can be given to prove that $e+f \sim f+e \sim f$, $f + (-f) \sim e$, $(f+g)+h \sim f+(g+h)$ and commutativity.

I wrote those homotopies by hand heavily using convexness of $I^n$. In my notes I have an observation which states that with the same process we can consider something more general, as $[\mathbb{S}^n \wedge X,Y]^0$ which of course gives the homotopy groups as a particular case taking $X = \mathbb{S}^0$. I was wondering who are those groups? There's an easy way to show the structure of groups as in the usual homotopy groups?

Comment: As $-\wedge X$ is left adjoint to $Map_\ast(X, -)$, then so long as $X$ is a CW-complex $[\mathbf{S}^n\wedge X, Y]^0$ will be isomorphic to $[\mathbf{S}^n, Map_\ast(X,Y)]^0=\pi_n Map_\ast(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $[X, Y]$ is a group whenever $X$ is a $H$-cogroup (i.e., cogroup object in the homotopy category of pointed spaces).  In particular, all suspensions are $H$-cogroups, with the comultiplication given by the "pinch" map.  So $[S^n \wedge X, Y]$ is a group if $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Do you have any reference or recommendations of good books about it?

Comment: This kind of thing is "abstract nonsense", so it seems it's not often written down.  Upon some googling I found the book *Algebraic Topology from a Homotopical Viewpoint* by Aguilar, Gitler, and Prieto, which talks about this approach in sections 2.9 - 2.10.  (Disclaimer: I have not read this book.)

Comment: @jacopoburelli In "Homotopical Topology" Fomenko, Fuchs discuss that in Lecture 4: Natural Group Structures in the Sets $\pi(X,Y)$. Co-$H$-spaces is what they call $H'$-spaces there.